# A nice exercise to prove or disprove that a subspace is path connected

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=[-1,1]\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ endowed with the topology

$\tau=\{U\subseteq X \quad|\quad 0\notin U\} \quad \cup \quad \{U\subseteq X \quad | \quad (-1,1)\subseteq U\}$.

Prove or disprove that $(-1,1)$ is a path connected subspace of $X$.

I've proved that $(-1,1)$ is connected showing that there are no open, non empty, disjointed sets in $X$ such that $(-1,1)$ is the union of them.

For the path connection, I try with the following function

$\gamma: [0,1] \to (-1,1), \quad \gamma(t)=ty+(1-t)x$

but I think that it doesn't work because I can't show that is continuous.

Anyone who can give me suggestions? Thanks.